# Post file from Bash shell script

Tags: bash, curl

I need to post a PowerPoint file to an online service which converts PPT files to PDF. I am new to Bash shell and don't know how to post PPT file from my local computer. How should I modify line below?

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/pdf" -X POST http://do.convertapi.com/PowerPoint2Pdf > output
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`--data-binary <data>`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary) option.

```
$ curl --data-binary @your.pdf ...
```